# Variable not switching to True?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have a variable called left and it should turn to true when I hit the left arrow key but it doesn't seem to switch to true. It should also call the sprite walking left animation as a result of left turning true but obviously that isn't working I just need to know why the variable won't turn to true.

```
import pygame
import random
import math
pygame.init()
screenwidth = 500
screenheight = 500
win = pygame.display.set_mode((screenwidth, screenheight))
pygame.display.set_caption('First Game')
bkg = pygame.image.load('2.jpg')
char1 = pygame.image.load('guy.png')
char1 = pygame.transform.scale(char1, (100, 100))
walkRight = []
walkLeft = []
Howmany = 4
for i in range(1, 13):
    walkRight.append(pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('R' + str(i) + '.png'), (100, 100)))
for i in range(1, 13):
    walkLeft.append(pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('L' + str(i) + '.png'), (100, 100)))

GameO = pygame.image.load('GO.jpg')
rock = pygame.image.load('b.png')
rock = pygame.transform.scale(rock, (100, 100))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


class player(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.GameOver = False
        self.vel = 10
        self.walkCount = 0
        self.left = False
        self.right = False
        self.lives = 3
        self.hit = 0
        self.hit1 = False
    def draw(self, win):
        if self.walkCount + 1 >= 27:
            self.walkCount = 0

        if self.left == True:
            win.blit(walkLeft[self.walkCount // 3], (self.x, self.y))
            self.walkCount += 1
            print ("hey we should be walking left right now ")
            pygame.display.update()
        elif self.right == True :
            win.blit(walkRight[self.walkCount // 3], (self.x, self.y))
            self.walkCount += 1
        else:
            win.blit(char1, (self.x, self.y))


class rocky():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = random.randrange(0, 430)
        self.y = -100

    def draw(self, win):
        win.blit(rock, (self.x, self.y))



def redrawgamewindow():
    win.blit(bkg, (0, 0))
    man.draw(win)
    rock1.draw(win)
    pygame.display.flip()

def collided (rockx, rocky, manx, many):
    man.hit = 0
    distance = math.sqrt((math.pow(rockx-manx, 2) + (math.pow(rocky-many, 2))))
    if distance < 75:
        man.hit += 1
        print("we be touched")
        man.hit1 = True
    else:
        man.hit1 = False


my_list= []

for number in range(Howmany):
    my_object = rocky()
    my_list.append(my_object)
rock1 = rocky()

man = player(250, 400, 100, 100)
run = True
while run:
    print (man.left)
    # Setting fps
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                run = False
    # Getting keys pressed
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and man.x > 0:
        man.x -= man.vel
        man.left = True
        man.right = False

    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and man.x < 500 - man.vel - man.width:
        man.x += man.vel
        man.left = False
        man.right = True


    for rockk in my_list:
        rock1.draw(win)
    else:
        man.left = False
        man.right = False
        man.walkCount = 0
    rock1.y += 5
    if rock1.y >= 500:
        rock1.x = random.randrange(0, 430)
        rock1.y = -100
    if man.hit1 == True:
        rock1.x = random.randrange(0, 430)
        rock1.y = -100

    if man.hit == 1:
        man.lives -=1
    if man.hit ==2:
        man.lives -=1
    if man.lives <= 0:
        print("THE GAME IS OVER ")
        exit()

    collided(rock1.x, rock1.y, man.x, man.y)

    redrawgamewindow()

    win.blit(pygame.image.load('R1.png').convert_alpha(), (200, 200))
```

Comment: You are unconditionally setting both `man.left` and `man.right` to `False` before ever calling `man.draw()`.  I guess you don't understand what an `else` after a `for` loop means - it gets executed *unless* the loop was broken out of (which can't happen in your code).

Comment: well thanks for the help im very new to python as you can tell.

Answer (score 0):

You have misplaced the `else` case. You accidentally put the `else` case at the end of `for` loop ([`else` clause](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement)) and not after the `if`-`elif` statement:

```py
if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and man.x > 0:
    man.x -= man.vel
    man.left = True
    man.right = False

elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and man.x < 500 - man.vel - man.width:
    man.x += man.vel
    man.left = False
    man.right = True

# INSERT
else:
    man.left = False
    man.right = False
    man.walkCount = 0

for rockk in my_list:
    rock1.draw(win)
# DELETE
#else:
#    man.left = False
#    man.right = False
#    man.walkCount = 0
```